# how to update multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I want to update the subject and other fields by adding multiple subjects, but the issue is it only saves one of subject which I have checked.

How can I solve this issue ?

**Below is my code :**

```
<?php
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
$host="localhost";//host name  
$username="root"; //database username  
$word="";//database word  
$db_name="tuichk";//database name  
$tbl_name="data"; //table name  
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string 
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name =$_REQUEST['name'];
$stu_ic = $_REQUEST['stu_ic'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$checkbox1=$_REQUEST['subject'];
$chk=""; 

$update="update data set name='".$name."', stu_ic='".$stu_ic."', address='".$address."', contact='".$contact."', sub='".$checkbox1."' where id='".$id."'";
mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
$status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
}else {
?>
```

this is my html form

```
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
<p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" /><input type="text" name="stu_ic" placeholder="Enter Student IC" required value="<?php echo $row['stu_ic'];?>" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>" /><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Enter Contact" required value="<?php echo $row['contact'];?>" /></p>
<div style="text-align:center">
   <div style="width:400px;border-radius:6px;margin:0px auto">  
<table border="1">  
   <tr>  
      <td colspan="2">Select Subject:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Bahasa Melayu</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Bahasa Melayu"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>English</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="English"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Mathematics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Mathematics"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Science</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Science"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Sejarah</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Sejarah"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Geography</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Geography"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Additional Mathematics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Additional Mathematics"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Chemistry</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Chemistry"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Physics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Physics"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Biology</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Biology"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Principle Of Accounting</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Principle Of Accounting"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Ekonomi Asas</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Ekonomi Asas"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Perdagangan</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Perdagangan"></td>  
   </tr>  
</table> 
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: can you please show us your html form?

Comment: The form elements must have an array indicator as part of the name i.e. <input type="text" name="subject[]">. Then in php you can pick up all of the values send i.e. $stu_icArr = $_REQUEST['stu_ic'];

Comment: update the question with  the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML input should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject1">
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject2">
```

In PHP have many options.

Option 1:

save subjects as string

```
$subjects = implode(',', $_POST['subject']);
```

retrieve as string and convert to array

```
$subjects = explode(',', $field);
```

Option 2: can save as JSON and retrieve as JSON and decode it.

Comment: sir, i have try this one but error occurred as 
Undefined variable: field in & Array to string conversion in

Answer (score 1):

this is my code inc html form:

```
<?php
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
$host="localhost";//host name  
$username="root"; //database username  
$word="";//database word  
$db_name="tuichk";//database name  
$tbl_name="data"; //table name  
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string 
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name =$_REQUEST['name'];
$stu_ic = $_REQUEST['stu_ic'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$checkbox1=$_REQUEST['subject'];
$subjects = implode(',', $_POST['subject']);
$subjects = explode(',', $field);
$chk=""; 

$update="update data set name='".$name."', stu_ic='".$stu_ic."', address='".$address."', contact='".$contact."', sub='".$checkbox1."' where id='".$id."'";
mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
$status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
}else {
?>
<div>
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
<p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" /><input type="text" name="stu_ic" placeholder="Enter Student IC" required value="<?php echo $row['stu_ic'];?>" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>" /><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Enter Contact" required value="<?php echo $row['contact'];?>" /></p>
<div style="text-align:center">
   <div style="width:400px;border-radius:6px;margin:0px auto">  
<table border="1">  
   <tr>  
      <td colspan="2">Select Subject:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Bahasa Melayu</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Bahasa Melayu"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>English</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="English"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Mathematics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Mathematics"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Science</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Science"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>Sejarah</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Sejarah"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Geography</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Geography"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Additional Mathematics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Additional Mathematics"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Chemistry</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Chemistry"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Physics</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Physics"></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>  
      <td>Biology</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Biology"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Principle Of Accounting</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Principle Of Accounting"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Ekonomi Asas</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Ekonomi Asas"></td>  
   </tr><tr>  
      <td>Perdagangan</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Perdagangan"></td>  
   </tr>  
</table> 
</div>  
</form>  
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: sir, i have found a solution by replace $checkbox1=$_REQUEST['subject']; to $subjects = implode(',', $_POST['subject']);
u comment very helpful. ty sir. may God bless u